# Is it allowed to add tags to "extend audience"?

Tags: discussion, tags

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38814198/preferred-database-encoding-on-windows seems to have been tagged [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) and [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) primarily to "extend the audience".

So I was wondering if that's OK or not.

Because to me there isn't a question on C or C++ in there, per se. But of course there are also "umbrella" tags like [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows), which cover everything but the kitchen sink (unless it runs Windows).

Comment: "Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer" so, if the experts of the tag aren't able to provide the best answer possible or is irrelevant to them, I would say that that tag should not be added.